# $||(z^{b_{1}}, \dots, z^{b_{r}}) - (0,....0) ||< r^{\max\left\{b_1,\dots,br\right\}}$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be a neighborhood of $0=(0,\dots,0)$.
If $z=(z_1,\dots,z_n) \in U$ then there exists $r>0$ such that $|z-0|<r$.

Fix $b_1,\dots,br \in \mathbb{Z}^{n}_{+}$, where $b_i=(b_{i}^{1},\dots,b_{i}^{n})$.
We have to $z^{b_i}=z_1^{b_{i}^{1}}\cdots z_n^{b_{i}^{n}}$.

**Question:** can I say that
$$||(z^{b_{1}}, \dots, z^{b_{r}}) - (0,....0) ||< r^{n|b_i|}$$
is true?

Attempted answer:
I am considering the maximum norm.
So, we have  $|z|= \max \left\{|z_i|\right\} < r$.
Then
$$||(z^{b_{1}}, \dots, z^{b_{r}}) - (0,\ldots,0) ||= \max \left\{|z_1^{b_{i}^{1}}\cdots z_n^{b_{i}^{n}}|\right\} = |z_1^{b_{j}^{1}}\cdots z_n^{b_{j}^{n}}|$$

Since $ |z_j^{b_{i}^{j}}|=|z_j|^{b_{i}^{j}} < |z|^{b_{i}^{j}}< r^{b_{i}^{j}}<r^{|b_i|}$, $j \in \left\{1,\dots,n\right\}$, we have
$$||(z^{b_{1}}, \dots, z^{b_{r}}) - (0,\ldots,0) ||=|z_1^{b_{j}^{1}}\cdots z_n^{b_{j}^{n}}|=|z_1^{b_{j}^{1}}|\cdots |z_n^{b_{j}^{n}}|<r^{|b_i|}\cdots r^{|b_i|}=r^{n|b_i|}$$

Comment: If I'm reading it right, you can have $z = \frac{1}{2}$, $r = \frac{3}{4}$, $b_1 = 1$, and $b_2 = 3$. Then the left side becomes approximately $0.51$ and the right side becomes approximately $0.42$.

Comment: What do you mean by the maximum of a set of vectors?

Comment: @J126 $z$  needs to be in $\mathbb{C}^n$

Comment: @ZoeAllen I will correct the text above and explain how I am trying to solve it.

Comment: what is $||.||$? There are a bunch of common norms in $\mathbb C^n$ like the $2$ norm, the infinity norm etc

Comment: @Conrad $||\cdot||$ is the maximum norm